# Change cursor to 'wait' on click and back to normal using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mouse-cursor

I need to change the cursor style to `wait` once a button is clicked with JavaScript. I have managed to do that, but when the user clicks the back button on the browser, the cursor remains on the `wait` state.

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    document.body.style.cursor='wait';
    document.getElementById('button').style.cursor='wait';
};

document.onload = function() {
    document.body.style.cursor='default';
};
```

I have tried to set the cursor to `default` when the page loads without refreshing the page, but it doesn't work. How can I set the cursor back to normal on the initial page if the user goes back?

Comment: This sounds impossible ... Is the page the user navigates with the back button also from your site?

Comment: @Teemu Yes, the start page is from my site.

Comment: Maybe it's something on the start page? Put `document.onreadystatechange=function(){console.log(document.readyState);}`  to the header section of the start page. The event should fire multiple times, and you should see "interactive" in the console at some point. If that state doesn't occur, there's something on the page, which prevents the document loading to finish.

Comment: @Teemu yes, it does log "interactive" on the first page load only, but the cursor remains on 'wait'.

Comment: Once a page is unloaded, and a new page is navigated to, all the content of the previous page should be gone, including styles. Are you sure the cursor isn't on "wait" also, when you come to the start page from somewhere else?

Comment: @Teemu I'm pretty sure the only time the cursor is set to 'wait' is when the button is clicked with the code I wrote on the question.